# How do i move a paragraph next to a heading

Tags: html, css

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCTpv.png]

```html
<html>

<body>
  <h1>heading</h1>
  <p>paragraph</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

I have searched but I cant find out how to move a paragraph nest to a heading.
like this:

HEADING paragraph

Comment: could you include your current HTML and CSS please?

Comment: For reference this is how to ask a question on Stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also, an indication of **how this is supposed to look**....because it will make a difference to the techniques used.

Answer (score 1):

`h1, p{ display:inline; vertical-align:middle;}`
By default, `h1` and `p` elements have a `display:block` rule, which makes them occupy a full width row. Setting them to `display:inline`, will make the elements occupy only as much as they contain(e.g. they will only take as much space as the text inside them), without no line breaks before and after them. Also check this linke for a good explanation regarding the additional issues with margins,padding, width properties, applied to inline elements: [Display rule clarification(external link)](http://maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline)

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: By default, `h1` and `p` elements have a `display:block` rule, which makes them occupy a full width row. Setting them to `display:inline`, will make the elements occupy only as much as they contain(e.g. they will only take as much space as the text inside them), without no line breaks before and after them. Also check this linke for a good explanation regarding the additional issues with margins,padding, width properties, applied to inline elements: http://maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/

Comment: Please add that to the answer itself. Comments can be deleted at any time. The reason for the comment was that the answer showed up in the Low Quality Review queue, probably due to its brevity. Adding that comment to the answer will remedy that.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your tag:

```html
<h1 style="display: inline;">HEADING</h1>
<p style="display: inline;">paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph
 paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph 
paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph 
paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph</p>
```

Comment: I'm neutral on this but while your code *works*, I suspect the result  is not what the OP was looking for

Comment: @Paulie_D the funny thing is that it had 2 upvotes wich now are gone. I'm just wondering why... what can I do better ... but as long it solves the question i'm OK with that

Comment: People changing their minds. I know I changed my mind on this a couple of times.

Comment: @Paulie_D but why, there is only one answer, and it's this one^^

Comment: @CodeiSir  I Don't know why but that doesn't work with my code the paragraph ends up overlapping my heading

Comment: @Jake_the_camper I don't know aswell. But maybe show me your code

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you use inline elements instead of making one out of block elements.

```css
.heading {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<span class="heading">heading</span>
<span>paragraph</span>
```

Both `p` and `h1` is suppose to be on their own line, so if you must, I suggest you give them a class name or else all of them will have the new display type.

```css
.inline {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="inline">heading</h1>
<p class="inline">paragraph</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really like styling listed as tag attributes. It makes for harder to read to HTML files and further complicates things if you later add a css file to your HTML document. If you don't want to link to an external css file then I personally would use the style tag in the head section of the HTML document.

```
<html>
<head>
   <title> page title here </title>
   <meta charset ="utf-8">
   <style>
   p, h1 {
   display: inline;
   }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <h1> Here is our heading!</h1>
   <p> and here is our paragraph next to it. </p>
</body>
</html>
```

However I believe this will still cause the paragraph to wrap around under the heading when it reaches a new line. If this isn't what you want then you will need to use some div tags. I would do something like this...

```
<html>
<head>
   <title> page title here </title>
   <meta charset ="utf-8">
   <style>
   .container {
       clear: both;
   }
   .headingDiv {
       float: left;
       width: 30%;
       display: inline;
    }
    .paraDiv {
        float: right;
        width: 70%;
        display: inline;
    }

   </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="headingDiv">
            <h1> Here is our heading!</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="paraDiv">
            <p> And here is our paragraph next to it. And here is our paragraph next to it. And here is our paragraph next to it.And here is our paragraph next to it.And here is our paragraph next to it.And here is our paragraph next to it.And here is our paragraph next to it.And here is our paragraph next to it.And here is our paragraph next to it.And here is our paragraph next to it.And here is our paragraph next to it. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="headingDiv">
            <h1> Here is our heading!</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="paraDiv">
            <p> And here is our paragraph next to it. And here is our paragraph next to it. And here is our paragraph next to it.And here is our paragraph next to it.And here is our paragraph next to it.And here is our paragraph next to it.And here is our paragraph next to it.And here is our paragraph next to it.And here is our paragraph next to it.And here is our paragraph next to it.And here is our paragraph next to it. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I have no idea what "I don't really like styling listed as tag attributes." means.